# How to send multiple inputs with the same name, but different value, through GET

Tags: html, input, get

How do i submit multiple values from inputs with the same name, through GET?

Fx:

```html
<form action="/gulv-finderen" method="get">
      <button disabled id="submitButton" class="btn">Send</button>
      <input disabled id="inputTaalerVand" type="hidden" name="pf_t_behov" value="Tåler vand" />
      <input disabled id="inputNemMontering" type="hidden" name="pf_t_behov" value="Nem montering" />
      <input type="hidden" name="pf_t_behov_and_condition" value="true" />
</form>
```

Ideally this shows up in the URL (when all are set to active) like:

/gulv-finderen?pf_t_behov=Tåler+vand&pf_t_behov=Nem+montering&pf_t_behov_and_condition=true

But what i get is:

/gulv-finderen?pf_t_behov=Nem montering&pf_t_behov_and_condition=true

It only accepts 1 of the values with the same name.

Is there any way i can prevent this, so that i can submit multiple inputs with the same name?

Comment: If You use `pf_t_behov[]` as name, server will recive array of values

Comment: You can't use the same time a key, else it will not be a key. Why don't use a list, like `key=arg1,arg2,arg3` or make multiple request ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456683/do-http-parameter-names-have-to-be-unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456683/do-http-parameter-names-have-to-be-unique)

Comment: @iPasha Doesent' work

Comment: @Elikill58 won't work if i submit it like that to the URL. It needs to be 1 GET request or it wont work

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Thnx. As far as i can read from that, it isn't possible :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the locate property to set up a custom URL string, and using JS to check which checkboxes were checked, and placing strings in the custom URL.

Who needs forms anyway?